# daily notification for content app

Tags: android

I want the users of my Android app to be notified about daily content updates.

I want the notifications to occur at a certain point in time during the day and I want to use the notification interface in Android to achieve that.

What is the best way to get it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `AlarmManager` to trigger a `IntentService` at the specific time, which creates the notification.